# Fastest way to read from and write to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, openxml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best / fastest way to export large set of data from C# to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844466/what-is-the-best-fastest-way-to-export-large-set-of-data-from-c-sharp-to-excel)

I am creating a web application with the following functionality:

1. Assume an admin stores some data in a predefined Excel template file. He will visit the Admin page and upload this Excel. The application reads this Excel and updates data in the database accordingly.
2. The data stored in the database has to be displayed to any user visiting the ViewDetails page. Now, the data should be displayed on screen to the user as well as a Download to Excel option has to be provided. Also, user will have option of filtering the data and sorting the data.

Assume that number of rows will be 10000+, and about 10-15 columns of text/numeric data in each row.

My current thoughts are to use the Interop.Excel object to read the Excel template and upload the data in the database. For reading, I usually fetch all my data into a DataTable and then display it as required. I plan to use DataView for my sorting and filtering purposes. However I have never worked with data of this magnitude and I am not sure about the performance using the above method.

My question is, what is the best and fastest way to go about realizing my requirement?
I read somewhere that it will take about 2-3 min to write that much data into an Excel file.

I also came across OpenXML:
"Open XML is an open standard for word-processing documents, presentations, and spreadsheets that can be freely implemented by multiple applications on different platforms."

Can I use it for better realizing the requirement or is there some other way?
I started developing C# web applications recently, and working with Excel spreadsheets for the first time, so please bear with me if there are any obvious answers I do not know about.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use epplus to load and save the excel-file.
It is very fast and versatile. Especially loading it is easy:

```
 Try
            Dim existingFile As New FileInfo(path)

            Using ExcelPackage As New ExcelPackage(existingFile)
                Dim Wsht As ExcelWorksheet = Nothing

                Try
                    Wsht = ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try


                Dim tbl As New DataTable
                Dim hasHeader = True
                For i = 1 To Wsht.Dimension.End.Column
                    tbl.Columns.Add()
'this is very "dumb" if you need better column names just iterate over the file and get them
                Next

                Dim startRow = 1 '1 due to the excel quirk
                For rowNum = startRow To Wsht.Dimension.End.Row
                    Dim wsRow = Wsht.Cells(rowNum, 1, rowNum, Wsht.Dimension.End.Column)
                    Dim row = tbl.NewRow
                    For Each cell In wsRow
                        row(cell.Start.Column - 1) = cell.Text
                    Next
                    tbl.Rows.Add(row)
                Next
'do something with the tbl datatable


            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

The drawback: only xlsx files are currently supported

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how much data you have, what you want to do (generate Excel sheets with full formatting for example), and your budget.

Excel Interop in my opinion is a bad idea. It is very error-prone, especially on a server. Actually, I would never run interop on a server simply because Office apps are built to be interactive, not to run multi-instance on a server.

Two methods I have used successfully are OpenXML (but this is hard to use) and the commercial Aspose Cells library. The latter is extremely fast and supports practically all Excel features and functions. You can read more about it at http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would look at codeplex there are several projects that do exactly what you want to do. Excel files are in open xml format but it can get really hairy really fast and its annoying. Then you can also use com but that's annoying as well.

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

fast data generation -- a new workbook with 500,000 cells of unique strings can be generated in less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should try multiple options: time them and see which gives the best performance for your situation. One option is the Interop that you mention. The other is using an [OLE DB connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with [JET SQL commands](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/jetsql/home.asp). Just be warned that the formatting can be easy to mess up; for instance, the sheet name must stay consistent with each upload, because that becomes the "table name" when writing a JET SQL query. Read through these [StackOverflow tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694422/beginner-tutorials-for-excel-programming-in-c-sharp).